# How to enter variable into prepared stmt that will retrieve all from the column?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search filter on my events website. There are 3 drop down inputs: Location, event type, date.

When the user submits the search filter, the form posts values that changes the mysql query which will display different events on the user screen. I'm having trouble finding a flexible solution.

Right now my query is like this:

```
$filter = $database->prepared_query("SELECT * FROM onlineevent WHERE event_location = (?) AND event_type = (?) AND event_date = (?)", array($l, $t, $d));
```

How can I make $l retrieve ALL possible values for event_location? The same goes for $t and $d. I thought I could set $l to '*' but that doesn't work.

The problem now is if the user doesn't select a value for $l, and they do select a value for $t and $d, then the query doesn't work. I want to set the default value for each variable to bring all results for each condition.

So if the user doesn't select any filter and submits the form, the query I'm looking for would look something like this:

```
$filter = $database->prepared_query("SELECT * FROM onlineevent WHERE event_location = (?) AND event_type = (?) AND event_date = (?)", array(ALL, ALL, ALL));
```

Comment: Dynamically create the conditions and *omit* them if you don't need them…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original version of [Ali_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57745436/5947043) was almost right, but made the mistake of including the whole clause as a parameter, rather than just the value. That would cause the whole clause to be seen as a string value, rather than as code with values within it.

The idea of building up the string gradually - and, crucially, only adding a clause if there's actually value specified in the search parameters - is correct though. You also need need to build up the parameter array separately at the same rate.

Here's a version which should actually execute correctly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM onlineevent";
$sqlfilters = "";
$parameters = array();

if( !empty($l) ){
  $sqlfilters .= " event_location = ?";
  $parameters[] = $l;
}
if( !empty($t) ){
  $sqlfilters .= ($sqlfilters != "" ? " AND" : "")." event_type = ?";
  $parameters[] = $t;
}
if( !empty($d) ){
  $sqlfilters .= ($sqlfilters != "" ? " AND" : "")." event_date = ?";
  $parameters[] = $d;
}

if ($sqlfilters != "") sqlfilters = "WHERE ".$sqlfilters; //add a WHERE clause if needed
$sql .= $sqlfilters; //add the filters to the initial SQL

$filter = $database->prepared_query($sql, $parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you but aren't you just looking for:

```
$filter = $database->prepared_query("SELECT * FROM onlineevent")
```

OR

```
$filter = $database->prepared_query("SELECT * FROM onlineevent WHERE event_location IS NOT NULL AND event_type IS NOT NULL AND event_date IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear and it is also not clear how the prepare function works, but here is my suggestion:

```
$array = array();
$query_parms = '';

if( !empty($l) ){
  $array[] = $l;
  $query_parms .= 'event_location = (?)';
}
if( !empty($t) ){
        $array[] = $t;
  $query_parms  .= count($array) > 1 ? 'AND event_type = (?)' : 'event_type = (?)';
}
if( !empty($d) ){
        $array[] = $d;
  $query_parms .= count($array) > 1 ? 'AND event_date = (?)' : 'event_date = (?)';
}

$filter = $database->prepared_query("SELECT * FROM onlineevent WHERE " . $query_parms, $array);
```

Comment: This is the right sort of idea but you can't use those SQL strings as parameters. The parameter must be only the value itself.

Comment: Thanks. But there's still an issue. what happens if the user didn't select any of the options? i.e. $l, $t and $d are all empty? Your query will crash.

Comment: you could simply check the array count if 0 then process query all.

Comment: Yes that's similar to what I did in my answer. I was simply pointing out the same thing in case you missed it